# Emacs linum highlighing

Tags: emacs, editor

I've recently moved to emacs and have a pretty simple question: when I'm on an specific line, linum changes it's foreground and background color. How can I disable this? What I'm trying to disable is the yellow foreground and grey background. I just get slightly distracted with it. [image: emacs]

Comment: The problem arises from your customizations. There's no issue with `emacs -q`.
Try turning off your customizations one by one until the problem is gone.
And consider using `compile`: with it line numbers are irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have [`linum-relative`](https://github.com/coldnew/linum-relative) installed, it uses the face `linum-relative-current-face` to highlight current line, you can customize it so that it is less distractive. Here is an example of disabling the highlight completely

```
(set-face-attribute 'linum-relative-current-face nil :background nil :foreground nil :weight 'normal)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works fantastically :).